# Callback - after_save but NOT create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can you separate callbacks so that `after_create` runs one set of code, but `!after_create`, so to speak, runs another?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? In my knowledge, `!after_create` is not a callback. Look here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: @Jatin - that was my point. I wanted to know how to accomplish a callback that only fires when a record is updated but not created.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`after_create` callback for new object, `after_update` for persisted one.

Comment: Does that answer the question asked above? If yes, please teach me how.

Comment: @Jatin As I understand question, yes. But I agree with you that a question wording is a little bit confusing.

Comment: Yes, the question is not clear enough, for us to argue over nothing.

Answer (score 4):

`after_create` After new object created

`after_update` After existing object updated

`after_save` Both creation and update

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple callbacks which only execute based on conditions

**model.rb**

```
after_create :only_do_if_this
after_create :only_do_if_that

def only_do_if_this
  if do_this?
    # code...
  end
end

def only_do_if_that
  if do_that?
    # code...
  end
end
```

You can also add the condition to the callback itself

```
after_create :only_do_if_this, :if => proc { |m| m.do_this? }
after_create :only_do_if_that, :if => proc { |m| m.do_that? }

def only_do_if_this
  # code ...
end

def only_do_if_that
  # code...
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to put both those conditionals on one callback line and still execute the callback if either condition satisfies or do the conditionals have to be separate?